# Xamarin Forms how to check it contains the latest Api for Android and iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi newbie on Xamarin Forms. 
 I am a bit of confuse on using Xamarin forms. 
With the following questions, I hope you can help me to understand to use it for development.

Currently I am using VS2015 Community version

1) If I have done the Settings on Cross Platform development to include C#/.Net(Xamarin v4...), do I still need to download the Xamarin at Xamarin.com?

2) Understand Android and iOS have different Api level (Sdk ver) and iOS ver8,9,10 respectively.
So, When google releases new api or Apple releases new iOS ver, How do I update Xamarin to  use them? what I need to and How I handle Android and iOS new update respectively? What are the steps to take?

3) If I have Updated Xamarin, is this means it has included all the latest Api for Android and iOS

4) Can I use Xamarin for VS2017 as compare to VS2015 is more matured?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can and should use latest and greatest tools available, unless you have some limitations. Use Visual Studio 2017, it provides an easy installation of Xamarin.

When a new version of platform SDK is released by Google or Apple for example, you will have to:

- Download & install new platform SDK for Android / iOS
- Update Xamarin.Forms nuget package in the project
- Additionally in case of iOS you may need to update Xcode

[Xamarin.Forms documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/) can answer all of your questions, so I suggest to get familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you'll need to add some steps. 
   First - try create Xamarin Forms project and buil it(for Android). If you have errors - please read [this manual](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/)
2. You need to check the update in several places.

2.1. About the new version Xamarin you will be informed Visual Studio.
    For VS 2015 Check next setting - Service - Parametrs - Update Xamarin(checked).

For VS 2017 - You'll see the checkbox on the top right.

2.2 About update Android Api -You must learn manually. Check in VS
  Service - Android - Package manager SDK Android. The new AIPI is a great event in the world of android - but you need to sit behind the news.

2.3 Also packages(Xamarin Forms and other) are updated - you need check nuget packages  for  your solution.

2.4. You must manual run update Xamarin for your mac. This is an extensive topic. Please read [this article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/mac/).

3. No is it. You need some manual actions(see item 2).
4. VS 2017 Has new features and new bugs ). I use VS 2017.